# Is it possible to create ant build file programmatically?

Tags: java, ant

Is it possible to create ant build file from java code using ant API?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No ANT api doesn't provide such feature. You'll have to use one of the following solution to "manually" write your build.xml file:

1. Serialization to file output stream
2. DOM + Xerces serialization to file output stream
3. SAX + Xerces serialization to file output stream

Answer (score 3):

If you do not need to stick to Java, the easiest way is to use groovy and groovy ant buillder (see [here](http://www.google.de/search?q=groovy+ant+builder)). Groovy is compiled into Java VM code and can be easily integrated into a Java program.

Answer (score 1):

This post may be able to help you.

In this post author is trying to run Java application from another application using ANT API.

[Java Applications From Java applications with Ant](http://www.baptiste-wicht.com/2010/08/tip-launch-java-applications-from-java-applications-with-ant/?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed:+BaptisteWicht+(%40Blog(%22Baptiste+Wicht%22)))